# How can I delete and refresh my listview?

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I have created a method deleteItem that would have to delete the row, but after I click the button it continues there and if I try again I got an exception.

```
public class WITHistory extends WITBase implements OnItemClickListener{
private ListView listView;
public int del;
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history_wit);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSearch);
    HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(this, searches);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected Row ["+pos+"]\n"+
"For donation data ["+searches.get(pos)+"]\n"+"With ID of ["+id+"]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    del = pos;

}

public void deleteItem(View v) {
    searches.remove(del);

}
```

}

Comment: you have to refresh the adapter with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), mind the adapter must be declared globally like you declared the int del

Comment: and also where is searches coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your adapter as class member

and add

```
public void deleteItem(View v) {
    searches.remove(del);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ().;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ishrat. I tried before using 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged (); and i didn't have success because i never declared my adapter as a class member :)

Comment: Why you not declaring you adapter globally ?